# WPF Showing / Hiding a control with triggers

Tags: wpf, mvvm, triggers

I'm new to WPF and I trying to create xaml logic to show / hide a control based on the value of the AllowMiscTitle on the ViewModel. The xaml consist of two fields a combobox of the standard tiles ("Mr", "Mrs", ..., "Other") when "Other" is selected I want the textbox to display.

I've created the follow xaml:

```
                <DockPanel Validation.Error="Validation_Error" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Titles, Mode=OneTime}" 
                      Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="TxtBxTitle" Margin="5,5" Visibility="Visible">
                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AllowMiscTitle}" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>

            </DockPanel>
```

Comment: To Which property your selected value of the comboBox is Binded..??

Answer (score 7):

That `Trigger` won't work because you have set `Visibility` property explicitly in `TextBox`

Do it like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtBxTitle" Margin="5,5">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=AllowMiscTitle}" Value="false">
                      <Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

The reason for this is [Dependency property value precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

There is a

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"></BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
```

You can use it as following

```
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding YourPropertyName, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"></TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right:-

If your selected value is binded to some property in the ViewModel like:-

```
private string _GenderType;

        public string GenderType
        {
            get
            {
                return _GenderType;
            }
            set
            {
                _GenderType= value;
 RaisePropertyChanged("GenderType");
```

In xaml:-

```
<TextBox.Style>
        <Style>
<Setter Property="TextBox.Visibility" value="Hidden"/>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">   
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=GenderType,ElementName=Combo1}" Value="Other">
                      <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
```