# How to switch Control by DataTrigger in the xaml?

Tags: wpf, styles, datatrigger

There is a window consist of the two control.
one is TreeView, the other is ListBox.

The code is as shown below.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Visible"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TotalCPUs}">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CPUSelectedCommand}"
                                 PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                 EventArgsConverter="{localConverters:SelectedItemConverter}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

Now I would like to change the value of the Visibility property of the Control whenever changes property of the ViewModel. (FilterMode True = ListBox Visible, FilterMode False = TreeView = Visible)

To this, I modified my XAML code as below.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Visible"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TotalCPUs}">
        <TreeView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterMode}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>                                
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Style>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CPUSelectedCommand}"
                                 PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                 EventArgsConverter="{localConverters:SelectedItemConverter}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterMode}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Below is the ViewModel code.

```
public class NewProjectViewModel : DialogViewModel
{
    private Generator projectGenerator = new Generator();

    public ObservableCollection<ClassHierarchyData> TotalCPUs { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<ClassHierarchyData>();
    public ObservableCollection<DetailType> FilterCPUs { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<DetailType>();

    private bool filterMode;
    public bool FilterMode
    {
        get => filterMode;
        set
        {
            if (this.filterMode == value) return;
            this.filterMode = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("FilterMode");
        }
    }

    private string cpuSearch;
    public string CPUSearch
    {
        get => this.cpuSearch;
        set
        {
            if (this.cpuSearch == value) return;
            this.cpuSearch = value;
            this.FilterCPUs.Add(new DetailType(typeof(Target), "abc"));
        }
    }

    private Type selectedTerminalItem;
    public Type SelectedTerminalItem
    {
        get => this.selectedTerminalItem;
        private set
        {
            if (this.selectedTerminalItem == value) return;
            this.selectedTerminalItem = value;

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTerminalItem");
        }
    }

    private Type selectedItem;
    public Type SelectedItem
    {
        get => selectedItem;
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedItem == value) return;
            this.selectedItem = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

            CreateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private string solutionName = string.Empty;
    public string SolutionName
    {
        get => this.solutionName;
        set
        {
            if (this.solutionName == value) return;

            this.solutionName = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SolutionName");
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SolutionFullPath");

            CreateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    private string solutionPath = string.Empty;
    public string SolutionPath
    {
        get => this.solutionPath;
        set
        {
            if (this.solutionPath == value) return;

            this.solutionPath = value;
            if(this.SolutionPath.Length > 0)
            {
                if (this.solutionPath.Last() != '\\')
                    this.solutionPath += "\\";
            }
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SolutionPath");
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SolutionFullPath");

            CreateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool CreateSolutionFolder { get; set; }
    public string SolutionFullPath { get => this.SolutionPath + this.solutionName; }

    private RelayCommand searchCommand;
    public RelayCommand SearchCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.searchCommand == null) this.searchCommand = new RelayCommand(this.OnSearch);

            return this.searchCommand;
        }
    }
    private void OnSearch()
    {
        CommonOpenFileDialog selectFolderDialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();

        selectFolderDialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
        selectFolderDialog.IsFolderPicker = true;
        if (selectFolderDialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            this.SolutionPath = selectFolderDialog.FileName + "\\";
        }
    }

    private RelayCommand<Action> _createCommand;
    public RelayCommand<Action> CreateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._createCommand == null)
                this._createCommand = new RelayCommand<Action>(this.OnCreate, this.CanExecuteCreate);

            return this._createCommand;
        }
    }
    private void OnCreate(Action action)
    {
        projectGenerator.GenerateSolution(this.SolutionPath, this.SolutionName, this.CreateSolutionFolder);
        action?.Invoke();
    }

    private bool CanExecuteCreate(Action action)
    {
        if (this.SelectedTerminalItem == null) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.solutionPath)) return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.solutionName)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    private RelayCommand<ClassHierarchyData> cpuSelectedCommand;
    public RelayCommand<ClassHierarchyData> CPUSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.cpuSelectedCommand == null)
                this.cpuSelectedCommand = new RelayCommand<ClassHierarchyData>(OnCPUSelected);

            return this.cpuSelectedCommand;
        }
    }

    private void OnCPUSelected(ClassHierarchyData selected)
    {
        this.SelectedItem = selected.Data;
        this.SelectedTerminalItem = (selected.Items.Count == 0) ? selected.Data : null;
    }


    private RelayCommand<string> navigateCommand;
    public RelayCommand<string> NavigateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.navigateCommand == null)
                this.navigateCommand = new RelayCommand<string>((uri) =>
                {
                    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(uri));
                });

            return navigateCommand;
        }
    }

    public NewProjectViewModel()
    {
        ClassHierarchyGenerator classHierarchyGenerator = new ClassHierarchyGenerator();

        this.TotalCPUs.Add(classHierarchyGenerator.ToHierarchyData(typeof(Target)));
        this.FilterCPUs.CollectionChanged += FilterCPUs_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void FilterCPUs_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.FilterMode = (this.FilterCPUs.Count > 0) ? true : false;
    }
}


public class DetailType
{
    public Type Type { get; }
    public string Path { get; }

    public DetailType(Type type, string path)
    {
        Type = type;
        Path = path;
    }
}
```

If user input data to the TextBox for filtering then the value of the CPUSearch is changed.

If the value of the CPUSearch is changed then be added test value into the FilterCPUs. (Note CPUSearch property)
when being added value into the FilterCPUs, FilterCPUs_CollectionChanged is called and the value of the FilterMode is changed.

But the above code does not work although be changed the value of the FilterMode. (works well except for functionality related to FilterMode)

Why doesn't the Control switch?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The XAML looks correct to me. Can you include the class containing the FilterMode property? Also, do you see any binding errors in the Output window while debugging? The ListBox doesn't appear to be bound so it won't show any items and you'll probably not see it unless you are adding items to it in code-behind.

Comment: The element of the ListBox appear. the above code works well except for control change functionality. Now I added ViewModel that binded.

Comment: The ViewModel needs to raise the PropertyChanged event for the binding to update the View.

Comment: Yes, I modified my code to call the RaisePropertyChanged function whenever FilterMode is changed. But not work still.
I updated the modified code.

Comment: I still don't see any code that raises the PropertyChanged event. Also, I see two constructors with different names: NewProjectViewModel and NewViewModel, and a duplicate copy of the FilterCPUs_CollectionChanged event handler. Can you include the entire ViewModel class?

Comment: it is my mistake in the process of editing. Yes, I would upload entire ViewModel source.

Comment: The code looks okay now. You will need to debug it further. Put a breakpoint on `this.RaisePropertyChanged("FilterMode")` and see if it triggers. Also check Output window for binding errors.

Comment: this.RaisePropertyChanged("FilterMode") is called but not work still. hm... maybe I should find other way.

Comment: Can you put a CheckBox in the View and bind it's IsChecked property to FilterMode to see if it indeed binds correctly?

Comment: Your strategy is correct (and much better than any other way), so you just need to determine what's failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by referring [WPF Showing / Hiding a control with triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718623/wpf-showing-hiding-a-control-with-triggers)

My XAML code updated like this and it works well.

Thanks for your interest.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <TreeView x:Name="treeView" BorderThickness="0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding TotalCPUs}">
        <TreeView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterMode}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterMode}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Style>

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedItemChanged">
                <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding CPUSelectedCommand}"
                                 PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                 EventArgsConverter="{localConverters:SelectedItemConverter}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TreeView>

    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" BorderThickness="0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding FilterCPUs}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="8" Text="{Binding Path=Path}" Margin="0 0 0 3"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type.Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CommonEnableBackgroundBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CommonEnableBorderBrush}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CommonEnableTextBrush}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterMode}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilterMode}" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.Style>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```